# C# Attribute To Auto Run Method

Tags: c#-4.0, custom-attributes

I'm not sure if this is completely possible. But what I would like to do is create an attribute that when I call a run method then all methods that have a particular run attribute are then ran.  I realize this can be done with delegates but I feel it might be a little cleaner looking if it can be achieved with an attribute.  I should note that the run order is not important.

Basic design:

```
//This is the method called that should start off the attribute chain
public void Run(){
  //calling logic in here
}

[AutomatedRun]
private void Method1(){

}

[AutomatedRun]
private void Method2(){

}
```

Comment: you would need to use reflection...find attributes for each method or property and then execute it by invoking the method for the attribute and then the method itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Attributes` are just metadata. They are useless unless you look for them and perform action. So in this case you need to get those methods that has `AutomatedRun` attribute using `Reflection` and call them:

```
var methods = typeof(YourClass)
     .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
     .Where(mi => Attribute.IsDefined(mi, typeof(AutomatedRunAttribute)));

foreach(var m in methods)
    m.Invoke(yourInstance);
```

Comment: In C# 9.0 you can use System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ModuleInitializer attribute

Answer (score 6):

In C# 9.0 introduced new attribute that named **ModuleInitializer**.
You can use it If your C# version greater than or equals 9.0.

I share below code for example:

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ModuleInitializer]
internal static void SomeMethod()
{
   ...
}
```

For more details you can visit these links:

[Module Initializers C# 9.0 draft specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/module-initializers),

[How to use .NET module initializers in a concrete real use case](https://www.cazzulino.com/module-initializers.html)

[Module Initializers In C# 9.0](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/module-initializers-in-csharp-9)

Comment: ModuleInitializer attribute usage has another advantages to call any async method like network calls etc.

Comment: Hi @RaminQuliyev, thanks for your comment. But method must be static void. For more information you can visit this link
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/module-initializers

Comment: Hi, Yes possible to use static async void also for async calls.

Comment: @RaminQuliyev I would not recommend using the async void method because you cannot use the await keyword to call it. Therefore  you may face some problems